# Why do I get this error when exporting an excel file to a CSV with Visual Basics?

Tags: excel, vba, csv

When the error message appears and I click debug it brings up the code in visual basics which I also have attached.

[image: Error Message]

To fix the problem we have to:
1.  Backspace the yellow highlighted line to the previous line
2.  Then return it to the original position. Doing so “moves” the yellow/error highlight to the next line.
3.  Continue “pushing” the yellow/error highlight to line 1If CICheck <> “CI” And Cost > 0 Then1
4.  Re-run program in VBE.
5.  Close VBE
6.  Exported `CSV` should exist in the `CSV` tab of the original Excel file.

```
 AltContract = Cells(j, 1)
 CICheck = Cells(j, 2)


If Len(AltContract) > 0 Then 'picking CI num between CI group or Alt CI
    SetContract = AltContract

Else 'no alt contract

    For i = 1 To 1000 'loop to set CI from above
    If Cells(j - i, 2) = "CI" Then '<~~~ ERRROR HERE
    BillDsc = Cells(j - i, 7)
    BillGrp = Cells(j - i, 6)
        Exit For
    End If
    Next
End If


If CICheck <> "CI" And Cost > 0 Then


Do Until Cells(j + i, 2) <> "CI"

    If Len(Cells(j + i, 1)) > 0 Then GoTo NextIteration

   i = i + 1
```

Comment: You should indent your code to line up your loops. Will make it easier for you to see what is going on

Comment: Your screenshot has no error message... What's the actual text of the error? ([edit] your question to include it!) - that said, unqualified `Cells` calls are implicit references to `ActiveSheet`, depending on *where* that code is written.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon there is a photo of the error. It just looks like 1 link, but there is really 2 there. Sneaky OP. `Run time Error 1004`

Comment: @urdearboy gah, got it. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

### You need to qualify your `Cells` object.

---

You can do this directly by using `Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j-1, 2)`
(Hopefully `j` here is an integer that is properly defined elsewhere in your code)

---

A faster way to do this would be to create a shortcut to your qualification by using:

```
Dim ws as WorkSheet
Set ws = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

and then reffering to your qualification by using `ws.Cells(j-1, 2)`

---

Another way to do this is use the `With` block.

```
Dim ws as WorkSheet
Set ws = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        .Cells(j-1, 2)
    End With
```

or

```
With Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Cells(j-1, 2)
End With
```